# Сортировка по другой таблице

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет, в общем есть такая задача, очень интересная.

У меня есть сущность пользователь, который связан связью многие-ко-мнгим с собой же (так сделаны лайки). Вопрос как мне сделать выборку из таблицы пользователей с сортировкой по лайкам?

Вот например если я лайку другого то в таблице `user_likes` запишется `id`, `from_user_id`, `to_user_id` - в общем если есть такая строка, то нужно это отсортировать и поставить наверх. И да при выдаче стоит `LIMIT 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  u.name AS name,
  COUNT(l.id) AS likes
FROM
  users AS u
LEFT JOIN
  users_likes AS l
ON
  u.id = l.to_user_id
GROUP BY
  u.name
ORDER BY
  COUNT(l.id) DESC
LIMIT 10
```